# restricting <form:select> from being databound to modelAttribute if a specific <form:option> is selected

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute, spring-form

I have a dropdown for a product category, which displays a set of values from the database.

For this I am using Spring  tag. I want one of the options to display a value called "Others" and when that value is selected I am displaying a textbox to accept a new product category.

The problem is when I am submitting the form, the product_category is being set as "Others,(newly added category)". but what I actually want is just the newly added category.

Is there any way to do this?

My code is as follows:

add.jsp

```
<form:form action="${actionURL}" method="POST" modelAttribute="Record">

..................
..................

                                <div class="row">
                                <section class="col col-4">
                                    <label class="label">Product Category</label> <label
                                        class="select"> <form:select id="product_category"
                                            path="product_category" onchange="add_new_productCategory();">
                                            <form:option value="">Choose category</form:option>
                                            <form:options items="${productOptions}"
                                                itemValue="product_category" itemLabel="product_category" />
                                            <form:option itemLabel="Others" value="Others"/>        
                                        </form:select><i></i>
                                    </label>
                                </section>
                                <section class="col col-4">
                                    <label class="label">New Category</label> <label class="input">
                                        <form:input type="text" path="product_category"
                                            id="new_product_category" disabled="disabled" required="required" />
                                    </label>
                                </section>
                            </div>

............................
...................

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">

.............................
```

I am using the following script

```
function() {
            if ($("#product_category").val() == 'Others') {
                $('#new_product_category').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('#new_product_category').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        };
```

which is getting executed when "others" option is selected

In my model class, it is just the usual process like

```
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY")
private String product_category;
```

In my controller I have

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRegisterPage(Model model) {
    System.out.println("-----------------add records ---------------------");

    model.addAttribute("Record", new RecordParams());

    List<ProductCategory> productOptions = listProductParamsService.findProductCategories();
    model.addAttribute("productOptions", productOptions);
    return "add";
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRecord(@ModelAttribute("Record") RecordParams recordParams) {
    System.out.println(recordParams);
    RegisterService.addRecord(recordParams);
    return "redirect:/add.html";
}
```

Everything is working as expected except for the product category, which when print is being displayed as

```
 RecordParams [id=null,................., product_category=Others,IPTL,....]
```

What should I do to rectify this, please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem, try to do as following suggestion this may help you:

If you want to submit Single `product_category`,
**Disable** `product_category` and **enable** `new_product_category` if `product_category` value is `Others` and vice versa...

```
function() {
    if ($("#product_category").val() == 'Others') {
        $('#product_category').prop('disabled', true); // disabled
        $('#new_product_category').prop('disabled', false);
    } 
    //else {
        //$('#new_product_category').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
       // $('#product_category').prop('disabled', false);
       // $('#new_product_category').prop('disabled', true); //disabled
    //}
};
```

Here once you **disabled** `product_category` you can not change its value so **else** part is useless,
To **enable** it again, write another function  on `focusout` or `blur` of `new_product_category` if its value is `""` i.e. **BLANK**

**Updated**:
Another way is, check `$('#product_category').val()`  on Form submit. If it is `Others` disable it.
Don't forget to add required attribute to `true` for `$('#new_product_category')`.

Comment: This cant be done and is not a good practice. If I disable the product_category select box, how will the user be able to come back and select a different option if he clicked "Others" accidentally and want to select a different option?

Comment: if user click on `Others` just `$('#new_product_category').focus()`,  and write `focusout` for this element , if Anyone left it as **blank** again enable `$('#product_category')`

Comment: @santaram_t Thankyou for your opinion. I also have founded another way to resolve it. please check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who have helped. I have found a better way of doing it.

I introduced a new field in my model

```
@Transient
private String select_product_category;
```

and then saved the selected value to this field and set this value to   product_category when its value is found null

I made the following changes to code.

```
<form:form action="${actionURL}" method="POST" modelAttribute="Record">

..................
..................

                            <div class="row">
                            <section class="col col-4">
                                <label class="label">Product Category</label> <label
                                    class="select"> <form:select id="product_category"
                                        path="select_product_category" onchange="add_new_productCategory();">
                                        <form:option value="">Choose category</form:option>
                                        <form:options items="${productOptions}"
                                            itemValue="product_category" itemLabel="product_category" />
                                        <form:option itemLabel="Others" value="Others"/>        
                                    </form:select><i></i>
                                </label>
                            </section>
                            <section class="col col-4">
                                <label class="label">New Category</label> <label class="input">
                                    <form:input type="text" path="product_category"
                                        id="new_product_category" disabled="disabled" required="required" />
                                </label>
                            </section>
                        </div>

 ............................
 ...................
```

And in my model class I made the following changes

```
@Transient
private String select_product_category;

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY")
private String product_category;

-----------------------------


    public String getSelect_product_category() {
    return select_product_category;
}

public void setSelect_product_category(String select_product_category) {

    if (!select_product_category.equals("Others")) {
        setProduct_category(select_product_category);
    } else {
        this.select_product_category = select_product_category;
    }
}

public String getProduct_category() {
    return product_category;
}

public void setProduct_category(String product_category) {
    if (product_category.equals(null)) {
        this.product_category = getSelect_product_category();
    } else {
        this.product_category = product_category;
    }
}
```

Now its working perfectly.